# Windows Run Scheduled Task After Wake Up with Command Line

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to use the command line to create a scheduled task that will run after I log into my account, whether it be for the first time on that day, or after resuming from sleep/hibernate and then logging in.

I found the `schtasks` command, and this looks very much like what I need to run a task after logon: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_logon

```
schtasks /create /tn TaskName /tr TaskRun /sc onlogon
```

After running my command, I can see my task name listed in the scheduled tasks list, but it never runs, regardless of whether I logon from a refresh restart or after resuming from sleep/hibernate. Here is my command:

```
schtasks /create /tn "AutohotKey Windows Logon Trigger" /tr "calc" /sc ONLOGON
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @frequency Have you tried the GUI to verify the settings of the task itself?

Comment: @Ramhound This scheduled task needs to be created and run by an automated script, so I couldn't use the GUI.

Comment: I didn't ask you to create it through the GUI I asked you verify the settings for the task itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex tasks it is easier to create the task in the GUI, export it as XML and then on the command line use `SCHTASKS /CREATE /tn TaskName /XML xmlfile`.

The event triggers in the GUI you likely want are listed as "At log on" and "On workstation unlock".